# How to listen on a server-side websocket non-blocking in Go

Tags: go, websocket, server, nonblocking, go-context

I use https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/net/websocket for creating a server-side websocket.  All communication through it is in JSON.  Thus, my code contains:

```
func wsHandler(ws *websocket.Conn) {
    var evnt event
    websocket.JSON.Receive(ws, &evnt)
    …
```

However, this blocks until the connection is closed by the client.  I know that this websocket package pre-dates context (and I know that there are newer websocket packages), still – is there really no way to wait for incoming frames in a non-blocking way?

Comment: use a new goroutine to handle the socket.  they're essentially free

Comment: What were you expecting? Some kind of async object that would notify you on a new message?

Comment: @Dolanor The best option is of course having a `ReceiveWithContext` variant. This does not exist. There is a bunch of SetDeadline functions, however, I fear that they interrupt an existing transfer, too, not just an idling connection. But I am not sure. Well, and possibly, I overlooked something.

Comment: Yes, SetDeadline, if reached, will interrupt Read. Just like a cancelled context would if ReceiveWithContext existed, I might add.

Comment: @Peter Thank you for the clarification about SetDeadline! Then it is useless for this purpose.

Comment: @erik258 I gave it a try and the goroutine solution might be the way to go. I was afraid of goroutine leaking but when the ws is closed, the `Receive` is aborted. BTW, this closing is done automatically if you return from your handler.

Comment: @erik258 If you create an answer from your comment, I’ll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this blocks until the connection is closed by the client.

The easiest way to handle concurrent blocking operations is to give them a goroutine.  Goroutines, unlike processes or threads, are essentially "free".

```
func wsHandler(ws *websocket.Conn) {
    go func() {
      var evnt event
      websocket.JSON.Receive(ws, &evnt)
      ....
   }()
}
```